# How to use int to get dictionary key value

Tags: dictionary

I have put some values into the dictionary and I'm trying to get the first key value from inventory but I cannot use inventory[] in combination with an int to retrieve the key value unlike a list. Is there any way to make this work?

```
Dictionary<string, Object> inventory = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

int selectCount = 0;
Console.WriteLine("You currently have selected: {0}", inventory[selectCount]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a collection of Keys, a collection of Values, or a collection of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`.  None of these collections is a list, i.e. none has an integer indexer, because a dictionary has no defined order.